# Twitterizer api search function throws exception

Tags: twitter, twitterizer

when i call for search function like:

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> result = TwitterSearch.Search("#hastag");
```

it throws exception like: Error converting value 0,148 to type 'Twitterizer.TwitterSearchResultCollection'. JsonParsingException.

im using the latest version of api. is there anything that i can do to solve it?